# Is `tail -f` more efficient than `less +F`?

Tags: tail, less

[This article](http://www.brianstorti.com/stop-using-tail/) pointed out some reasons to use `less +F` over `tail -f`. Most of the reasons are about the *features*, not *technical* reasons: `less +F` can highlight, search, navigate through file.

How about the *technical* reasons?

AFAIK, `less` uses polling each one second to update the file, while `tail`, as [POSIX defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html#tag_20_125_18) use a loop that sleeps for 1 second and copies any bytes that are available. This is sufficient but POSIX also encouraged implementation to use more efficient method. At least [GNU tail](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html) use [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify), so it's more efficient.

`less` also keeps the file content in memory, so with huge file, like a few gigabytes, it can slow down your computer.

So, is there any others *technical* reasons to use `tail -f` over `less +F`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think you've covered the main point: `less +F` reads the whole file, whereas on many systems `tail -f` only reads the end of the file, and even on the systems where it does read the whole file, at least it doesn't keep the whole file in memory. That makes `less +F` impractical for very large files. You can, however, run `less -n +F`, which causes `less` to read only the end of the file, at the cost of not displaying line numbers.

Under the hood, between `less -n +F` and `tail -f`, the main difference is that `tail` uses a file change notification service on some platforms (e.g., inotify on Linux), which allows it to display new data instantly, whereas `less` might take up to 1 second to display the new data because it checks for new data in a loop and sleeps between checks.

Another difference between `less +F` and `tail -f` is that `less` will invoke its input filter, but that usually won't have any impact on log files.

A technical difference which is in favor of `less +F` is that you can make it truncate lines at the screen width with the `-S` option, whereas `tail` gives you no choice but to display the whole line no matter how long it is.

Interface-wise, there's not that much of an advantage to using `less`. `tail -f` is useful to notice when something happens. You can even run it in the background. If something happens and you want to look at the file in more detail, you can open it in `less` in another terminal.

If you want to watch multiple files, [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) is the way to go. Even for a single file, multitail has additional nifty features such as filtering and colorizations.

Comment: With very large file, does 'less -n 99.99p +F' prevent less from reading the whole file?

Comment: @cuonglm Ah, right, it does. Just `less -n` is enough, that makes less use the seek-to-end-then-read-back strategy.