# How to quit `tail -f` mode without using `Ctrl+c`?

Tags: tail

When I do `tail -f filename`, how to quit the mode without use `Ctrl+c` to kill the process?

What I want is a normal way to quit, like `q` in `top`.

I am just curious about the question, because I feel that killing the process is not a good way to quit something.

Comment: `tail` is not interactive; it does not take commands.

Comment: @muru Hi, "tail is not interactive" means `tail -f` doesn't have normal quit way, the only way is using `Ctrl+c`?

Comment: In effect, yes. You can also kill it by doing `kill <pid>` or `pkill tail`, but all three do the same thing: send a signal to `tail` that kills it.

Comment: You question is quiet confusing. Do you want to use the command in  the script shell, so   use --pid=PID with -f, terminate after process ID, PID dies found in the man.

Comment: @dubis Thanks for your advise, I am just curious about the question, because I feel kill process is not a good way to quit something. I am Linux newcomer, sorry for if I asked a stupid question.

Comment: @muru Get it. Thanks for your answer, I am just curious about the question, because I feel kill process is not a good way to quit something. I am Linux newcomer, sorry for if I asked a stupid question.

Comment: Usually, yes, because the process may leave behind a mess (say, temporary files, or locked databases). `tail` doesn't do much, so it's perfectly alright to kill it.

Comment: There is also difference between killing process with SIGTERM (default) and SIGKILL. SIGTERM 'asks' process to stop, and this signal can be handled by program. On the other hand SIGKILL actually kills the process. See `man signal` for more

Comment: The premise of this question is faulty.  That special character does _not_ "kill" the process in the way that you are thinking.  It sends the _interrupt signal_ to it, not the _kill_ or _terminate_ signals.

Comment: @muru Thanks for your additional information, you could organize your comment in the answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: Minor detail, @mrc02_kr: Ctrl-C sends SIGINT (interrupt), not SIGTERM (terminate). But the practical effect (a 'request' for the process to stop) is the same either way.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonably to interrupt `tail` or even kill it without worry.  But if you want an alternative, consider `most`, which has an admittedly under-documented "follow" mode, initiated with Shift+F, and can be cleanly exited with Q.

Comment: The problem here is your perception that "killing the process is not a good way to quit something" -- sending ^C to a process *is* one way of saying "I'm done with you and I'd like you to stop", it *is* the "default" way to exit from a terminal process in Linux. If you're choosing to exit from some long running process, the repercussions of your choice to stop it may leave a mess, but `tail -f` isn't that :)

Comment: There's always `tail() { trap "stty intr '^c'" 2 0; stty intr q; command tail "$@"; }`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As said in the comments, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> does not kill the `tail` process, which is done by sending either a SIGTERM or SIGKILL signal (the infamous `-9`...); it merely sends a SIGINT which tells `tail` to end the forward mode and exit.

FYI, these's a better tool:

```
less +F filename
```

In `less`, you can press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to end forward mode and scroll through the file, then press <kbd>F</kbd> to go back to forward mode again.

Note that [`less +F` is advocated by many as a better alternative to `tail -f`](http://www.brianstorti.com/stop-using-tail/). For difference and caveats between the two tools, read this answer: [Is `tail -f` more efficient than `less +F`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193620/is-tail-f-more-efficient-than-less-f)

Comment: Off-topic.  The OP did not ask to "end the forward mode and scroll through the file". Rather, the OP asked how to quit tail -f without using Ctrl+C

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Given that the OP's question premise is incorrect (`tail` is not killed by CTRL-C and is not interactive) I believe my answer is more than appropriate.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 If you take the OP literally yes it's off-topic, however I prefer educational answers that address misunderstandings and at the same time give an answer to what the OP was *actually* trying to achieve, i.e. the **real** question.

Comment: _"Ctrl-C does not kill the tail process"_ - Yes it does. Or at least as much as `kill <pid>` does. For most programs, there's no real difference between `Ctrl-C` (=`SIGINT`), `SIGTERM` and, to some extent, `SIGKILL`. The default action for all three is to simply terminate the process, as if `exit()` had been called, with the exception that for `SIGKILL`, none of the user-mode code associated with `exit()` is called (so no `atexit()` cleanups etc). `Ctrl-C` and `SIGTERM`, in particular, are completely identical unless the program explicitly catches either and acts on it. GNU tail doesn't.

Comment: "*normal mode, where you can scroll up and down the file*" - is that some new version of `tail` of which I was previously not aware?

Comment: The signal sending function in Unix is called `kill`. Ctrl-C doesn't use it, but some sort of kernel internal equivalent.

Comment: @TobySpeight You're right, my mistake.  I corrected the post.

Comment: @marcelm Terminating the process is not the same as `exit()` being called. `exit()` will run the `atexit()` handlers, and clean up open stdio files (most importantly flushing output buffers).  A `SIGINT` handler could do this, but most programs don't bother; I don't know whether `tail` does.

Comment: Note that `less` is not always a better tool than `tail`, they're different and have different advantages. E.G. with `tail -f` I can press enter a few times to "mark" where I was, or I can use `tail -f | grep` (or awk, cut, etc)

Comment: @Barmar I stand corrected! `SIGTERM` / `SIGINT` termination indeed doesn't do that. However, this brings `SIGTERM` / `SIGINT` and `SIGKILL` even closer than I argued before ;)

Answer (score 19):

> What I want is a normal way to quit, like q in top.

That's <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> :)

> I am just curious about the question, because I feel that killing the process is not a good way to quit something.

`^C` (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) sends a [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals) to the process, which is defined as:

> The SIGINT signal is sent to a process by its controlling terminal when a user wishes to interrupt the process

That's exactly what you want to do here, is interrupt `tail`. There's no other way to accomplish what you're trying to do ("nicely" quit tail) and while other answers provide a means to stop `tail` in other ways, they're no better.

Pressing `^C` will attempt to interrupt a task in Linux -- this is perfectly normal, and it's only "not good" if that process is in the middle of something and you're not letting it finish, and then the only "not good" side effect is leftover things from that process. As an example, `^C` in the middle of a `make` command leaves partially-compiled software, but that's fine: a further run of `make` will clean that up / resume where it left off.

Comment: Actually, the `make` example is a reminder why we always write `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` in our Makefiles - we want Make to remove partially-written intermediate files when it learns that one of its commands received a signal.

Comment: Processes can trap `SIGINT` and do cleanup before exit as indicated in Toby's `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` example.

Comment: Yes, the ability to trap SIGINT is exactly why I said it's what @Arthur wants. There's no need to be "nice" to tail, you won't hurt it's feelings with a `^C` :)

Answer (score 12):

> `tail -f` filename, how to quit the mode without use <kbd>Ctrl c</kbd> to kill the process

You can't do that. Perhaps you wanted to run `tail -f somefile | less`

The <kbd>Ctrl c</kbd> is interpreted by the tty subsystem (and by your shell) and sends a `SIGINT` signal (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html)...). See [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

Answer (score 7):

This would work and answers your question, but is not a particularly satisfactory solution.

```
timeout 15s tail -f /var/log/messages
```

This will run the command for 15 seconds and then kill it for you, without having to press `^C`

Comment: Yeah, so would shutting down the computer `tail` is being run on. Still, you're not wrong I guess.

Comment: How is terminating `tail` with SIGTERM better than terminating it with SIGINT?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You're totally right - its not better.  But this answer directly answers the OP's question, even though its not really a lot of use in reality.  However I have used timeout to terminate things like ping, when using a Dell DRAC Java app that requires a menu selection to press Control and a second menu choice to release control (that was just irritating, a Dell c5220 blade )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function

```
function prll(){
..... 
pkill -9 -x tail
}
```

Assuming you run tail along your function

```
tail -n 1 -f file | 
pv -l > /dev/null | 
prll file

echo !!done!!
```

Conclusion, the answer is:

```
pkill -9 -x tail
```

Answer (score -1):

Answers differ based on context. To quit *tail -f* elegantly, you will need a trigger. 
Assume you are trying to monitor output of a task that will finish at some point in time - that can become your trigger.

```
task >& filename.log &
task_pid=$!
tail -f filename.log &
tail_pid=$!
while [ 1 ]
do
    # -0 is a special "poke" signal - "are you around?"
    kill -0 $task_pid
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        # Original task is still alive.
        sleep 2
        continue
    fi
    kill -TERM $tail_pid
    break
done
```

I have used similar ideas in the past.

Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

I think another good approach is using the old ps + kill in another session.

```
ps -fea | grep tail
```

The above command would identify any tail running by any user, and after finding the right PID, just run kill. For example:

```
kill 999999
```

Hope this can help someone as an alternative approach.

Comment: That does exactly what the OP wanted to avoid (»I feel that killing the process is not a good way«). Your answer is not only more complicated, it makes things worse by sending SIGTERM, while the simple ctrl-c would send a smooth SIGINT.

Answer (score -2):

Issuing

```
echo tail -n 1 -f <filename>
```

works for me though I'm not 100% sure it terminates the tail process.

Comment: The command you show does not do anything other than output the strings `tail`, `-n`, `1`, `-f` and the filename with spaces between them.