# less -n default behavior, is not the same as indicated through man

Tags: command-line, less

For a MacOS and Ubuntu Server 20, with the command `man less` I can read the following:

```
 -n or --line-numbers
              Suppresses line numbers.  The default (to use line numbers) may cause less to run more slowly in some cases, especially with a very large input file.  Suppressing line  numbers  with
              the  -n  option will avoid this problem.  Using line numbers means: the line number will be displayed in the verbose prompt and in the = command, and the v command will pass the cur‐
              rent line number to the editor (see also the discussion of LESSEDIT in PROMPTS below).

 -N or --LINE-NUMBERS
              Causes a line number to be displayed at the beginning of each line in the display.
```

The reason of this post is about the `-n` (lowercase) parameter that contains the `The default (to use line numbers)` part. For the both OS mentioned if I did do:

- `less /path/to/filename.txt`

It displays the data without the line numbers, *it is the contrary as indicated* above.

Of course If I want see the line numbers I use:

- `less -N /path/to/filename.txt`

It works as indicated. Therefore:

```
less    /path/to/filename.txt
less -n /path/to/filename.txt
```

Is practically the same.

Am I missing something?

BTW with `less --help`

```
-n  -N  ....  --line-numbers  --LINE-NUMBERS
                  Don't use line numbers.
```

Not very clear, is confuse.

I created this post due the following valuable post:

- [Is `tail -f` more efficient than `less +F`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193620/is-tail-f-more-efficient-than-less-f)

Where indicates in the solution:

```
You can, however, run "less -n +F", which causes "less" to read 
only the end of the file, at the cost of **not** displaying line numbers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`less` displays line numbers in two ways:

- at the start of each line, if `-N` is used;
- in the status line at the bottom of the screen, when verbose prompts are enabled (`less -M`; this will show the number of the first line shown, the last line shown, and the total number of lines).

`-n` disables the latter, as well as the former. In particular, determining the total number of lines can be expensive; that’s why the option is useful. When line numbers are disabled using `-n`, `less` shows the position in the file in bytes.

My version of `less` has the following in `less --help`:

```
  -n  ........  --line-numbers
                  Don't use line numbers.
  -N  ........  --LINE-NUMBERS
                  Use line numbers.
```

The behaviour of `-n` is described in the information you show:

> Using line numbers means: the line number will be displayed in the verbose prompt and in the = command, and the v command will pass the current line number to the editor

This doesn’t mention line numbers at the start of each line.